# NoReverseMatch at /admin/r/1/APT2/ Reverse for 'apartment_create' not found. 'apartment_create' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display a template on Django 3.0 and I get NoReverseMatch Error. Obviously, the url.py and views.py fail to show the template. I am on admin page adding a new record, but when I click show on site, I get this error. 
1) What is the first part of `admin/r/1/APT2` url mean especially the `r/1`? I believe this should redirect to apartment_create.html, but the view function does not exist or there is no url by that name. But according to me, there is.

`NoReverseMatch at /admin/r/1/APT2/
Reverse for 'apartment_create' not found. 'apartment_create' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

views.py

```
class ApartmentCreate(CreateView):
    # make a form based on this model
    form_class=ApartmentForm
    # if we only want to edit these two fields
    # fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    fields = '__all__'


    class Meta:
        widgets = {'geom': LeafletWidget()}

    # render this html file, pass a form object to that file
    template_name = 'rent_app:apartment_create.html'
    #template_name = 'rent_app/form_template.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('rent_app:apartment_create_success')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
app_name = 'rent_app'


urlpatterns = [

        path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('apartment_create/<slug:apt_id>', views.ApartmentCreate.as_view(), name='apartment_create'),
        path('apartments/<int:pk>/', views.ApartmentUpdate.as_view(), name='apartment_update'),
        path('apartments/<int:pk>/delete/', views.ApartmentDelete.as_view(), name='apartment_delete'),
```

Comment: You are missing a '/' in your url. You need `'apartment_create/<slug:apt_id>/'`

Comment: @Daniel HolmesThanks. But the NoReverseMatch is not resolved.